# Multiset sum of $n$ spheres equaling the multiset sum of $m$ spheres, $m\ne n$

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'll put the question at the top, then explain.

**By *sphere* we shall mean any subset of $\Bbb R^3$ which is homeomorphic to a sphere. Can the multiset sum of $m$ spheres equal the multiset sum of $n$ spheres, $m\ne n$?**

To explain what I mean by this, let's discuss a simpler version of the same problem.

---

A long time ago I came up with, and subsequently disproved, a conjecture about multiset sums of arcs in the plane.

To set the stage: an *arc* (or a *Jordan arc*) is a non-self-intersecting curve with two distinct endpoints. Formally, it's a subset of the plane homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. The *multiset sum* of two sets is like their union, but counting multiplicity. (The result is an object called a *multiset*, which is like a set except that elements can appear multiple times - in other words, every element has a *multiplicity*.)

The question I wanted to ask was: If the multiset sum of $m$ arcs in the plane equals the multiset sum of $n$ arcs in the plane, must $m=n$?

(Before we go on, a quick nonexample: $[0,1]+[1,2]$ and $[0,2]$ is not a counterexample because the multiplicity of $1$ is different.)

Spoilers if you wish to think about this on your own, but...

...in fact, the answer is *no*. There's a counterexample with $m=2$ and $n=3$ ([see this album for larger images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Lq8.jpg)):

[image]

You can see the final configuration [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tdma.png), where (unlike in the three images above) dots mark points of multiplicity two. (Note that the center has multiplicity two as well. The fact that the multiplicity of the center is the same on both sides of the equation is, to me, the most remarkable part of this.)

In words: *shoot a line through the heart of a double spiral.*

---

So now the next question. Let's go up a dimension!

**By *sphere* we shall mean any subset of $\Bbb R^3$ which is homeomorphic to a sphere. Can the multiset sum of $m$ spheres equal the multiset sum of $n$ spheres, $m\ne n$?**

Since this is possible with arcs, I imagine the answer is "yes", but I'm having trouble creating an example. (What's the 3D equivalent of a double spiral? I'm having trouble visualizing it.)

---

A small note about the arc solution.

An Euler characteristic argument shows that this must be in some sense "wild": the arcs must intersect in infinitely many pieces. The reason is that, no matter how you decompose an arc into finitely many "vertices" and "edges", the quantity $V-E$ (vertices minus edges) always equals $1$. Therefore, if you're given a multiset which can be decomposed into finitely many disjoint vertices and edges (though with multiplicity), $V-E$ tells you how many arcs went into it.

For example, consider a $\Large\times$ shape where the center has multiplicity two and all other points have multiplicity one. Then the Euler characteristic is $6-4=2$, telling us that this shape is the sum of two arcs.

The counterexample above gets around that because its Euler characteristic is $\infty-\infty$, which is undefined.

I mention this because: (a) If I asked for loops (subsets of the plane homeomorphic to $S^1$), this question would be boring. A triangle plus its medial triangle equals the sum of three small triangles. This reflects the fact that the Euler characteristic of a loop is zero. (b) The Euler characteristic of a sphere is $2$, meaning that we need some "wild" configuration as well, or else $\frac12(V-E+F)$ will tell us how many spheres went into it.

Comment: For bonus points, do it where every sphere involved is ambiently isotopic to the standard one.

Comment: Should I put the images in a spoiler block? (I'd just have to put ">! " in front.) Yay or nay